# How does django differentiate between 2 management forms on same page?

Tags: django, validation, formset

I have 2 formsets based on 2 different models.

While debugging a validation problem where my formsets were failing  is_valid validation (see errors below):

```
(Pdb) FormsetItem.errors
[{'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}, {'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}]
```

I noticed that when I render the management form for the 2 formsets:

```
{{ FormsetItem.management_form }}
{{ FormsetCat.management_form }}
```

It creates the exact same HTML for both:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="26" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" value="26" id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" value="0" id="id_form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" value="1000" id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" />
<input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="26" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" value="26" id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" value="0" id="id_form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" value="1000" id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" />
```

How does django differentiate which management form is for which formset? My suspicion is that this is what is causing my validation errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Apologies for deleting my answer. I misread your question.

Comment: On the contrary, your answer was spot-on and solved my problem. I suggest you repost your answer so that you can get credit for it, and help other users who have come up with the same problem. My problem was in thinking that prefixes are for different instances of forms in a formset. Turns our prefixes are necessary whenever there are multiple formsets in one form. I would have thought django developers would have just given each management form a unique name. would be the most logical solution.

Comment: Guess I've been too hasty twice! Thanks for nudging me to un-delete.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two forms within the same `<form>` tag (or, really, just on the same page), you should [pass a `prefix` to the forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms), to help django to tell them apart.

Comment: I see. I thought prefixes were intended for django to differentiate between instances in the same formset (if necessary). I would have expected django to create a unique ID for each management form to identify it to a specific formset, since each formset has its own management form... sounds like it would be the most logical thing no?